# WindowsAppSDK doesnt have ProtocolActivatedEventArgs

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3, application-lifecycle, windows-app-sdk

I am trying to handle protocol activation and as per docs I should handle all of that within **OnLaunched** method so that is what I am trying to do here, but **Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs** doesnt exist.

[image]

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var activatedArgs = AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();
    var e = args.UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs;
    InitializeRootFrame(e);
    if (activatedArgs.Kind is ExtendedActivationKind.Launch)
    {
        if (!e.PrelaunchActivated)
        {
            if (RootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
    else //Launched by some other means other than normal launching
    {
        try
        {
            if (activatedArgs.Kind is ExtendedActivationKind.Protocol && activatedArgs is Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                //var a = activatedArgs.Data as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                var queryParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(activatedArgs.Data.Uri.Query);
                PocessQueryForToken(queryParameters);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
            Window.Current.Activate();
            HasLaunched = true;
        }
    }
    HasLaunched = true;
}
```

Comment: It's not supported (yet?). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73217714/2411960) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only a **[AppActivationArguments Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.applifecycle.appactivationarguments?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1)** in the `Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle NameSpace`. So the behavior you got is expected because you are looking for a class that doesn't even exist.

Based on the document for **AppActivationArguments**, we could know that the `activatedArgs` we got contains a data object which has one of the following data types, depending on the activation type specified by the Kind property.

- File      ->IFileActivatedEventArgs
- Protocol   ->IProtocolActivatedEventArgs
- StartupTask  ->IStartupTaskActivatedEventArgs

The **IProtocolActivatedEventArgs** should be the thing that we are looking for. The document here-[ProtocolActivatedEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.protocolactivatedeventargs?view=winrt-22621) shows that this Class comes from the **Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation Namespace**.

So the code should looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var eventargs = Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();
        if (eventargs.Kind is ExtendedActivationKind.Protocol && eventargs.Data is Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs ProtocolArgs = eventargs.Data as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            var uri = ProtocolArgs.Uri;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the namespace "Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation" for uwp ? I saw it that I could access that class as u can see in commented code but I wasnt sure if that should be used in windowsAppSDK project.

Comment: @MuhammadTouseef Yes, this is the API from UWP. Based on the document I posted, this is the class used in the Windows APP SDK for Protocol activation.