# deep linking doesn't get Uri

Tags: windows, maui, deep-linking

I was searching on the internet, for answers regarding registration of Custom URI on Maui for Windows.

One of my findings was this answer.

[How to open WinUI Maui through URI Activation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606737/how-to-open-winui-maui-through-uri-activation)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-protocol

I was change it per my requirements.

I am using daily api, so a meeting is https://demy-ia.daily.co/programming where programming is the name of the room

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
        <uap:Protocol Name="daily-co">
            <uap:DisplayName>demyia</uap:DisplayName>
        </uap:Protocol>
    </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

I have put this code in the MauiProgram

```
#if WINDOWS
                    events.AddWindows(windows => windows
                            .OnLaunched((window, args) => {

                                var activatedEventArgs = Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();

                            }));
#endif
```

The problem is that upon looking at the values, my Kind is Launch instead of protocol, also I don't have any URI.

I saw this screenshot.

[image]

but when I compare it to mine, I don't have anything.

[image: MauiProgram.cs]

Answer (score 0):

Well, as answer, [Leon Lu - MSFT's solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1503211/deep-linking-windows-confussion) can fix the problem:

Firstly, please right-click the `Package.appxmanifest` file, open with HTML Editor. I add following name-prefix to do it:

```xml
<Applications>
      <Application Id="App" ...> 

...         
         <Extensions>
              <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">             
                  <uap:Protocol Name="demy-ia">                      
                      <uap:DisplayName>demy-ia</uap:DisplayName>
                  </uap:Protocol>
              </uap:Extension>
          </Extensions>
     </Application>
  </Applications>
```

We can get url by `appActivationArguments.Uri`, before get the url, we need use `Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();` to get `appActivationArguments`.

Please change the events like following code:

```cs
.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
                {
#if WINDOWS
                    events.AddWindows(windows => windows
                            .OnLaunched((window, args) => {
                                
                                var activatedEventArgs = Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();
                               
                                Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs appActivationArguments =activatedEventArgs.Data as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;


                               if (appActivationArguments != null)
                                {
                                    var uri = appActivationArguments.Uri;
                                }
                               
                            }));
#endif


               })
```

Here is my tested url `demy-ia://Addyourtestmeeting`, if you put this URL in the browser and access it, you will get a popup window to open your application.

By the way, if you want to use `https://demy-ia.daily.co/dedwdewdewdew` to do the deep linking. Please Handle the Redirect from Web URL to Custom URI Scheme:

On the web server, configure a redirect from `https://demy-ia.daily.co/dedwdewdewdew` to `demy-ia://Addyourtestmeeting`.

**Note**: Please follow the steps in our [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/articles/67444/email-notifications.html) to enable e-mail notifications if you want to receive the related email notification for this thread.