How to detect CommandLineLaunch in MAUI windows and access passing parameters
I am migrating from Xamarin Forms to MAUI. In my Xamarin Forms Windows application, I can open it from the command line and pass parameters. I am able to open the app and access these parameters using code similar to the following in Xamarin.
Xamarin Froms-Windows

 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch)
     {
         var commandLine = args as CommandLineActivatedEventArgs;
         if (commandLine != null)
         {
             var operation = commandLine.Operation;
             var para = operation.Arguments;

             var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthPara>(para);

         }
     }

     base.OnActivated(args);
 }


But, in MAUI I did this but,

ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch is not detecting, activatedEventArgs.Kind is always Launch
How to access the parameters?

MAUI-Windows

public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(FormsWebView), typeof(FormsWebViewRenderer));
    });
    builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
    {
        events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
        {

            windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnActivated((window, args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    AppActivationArguments activatedEventArgs = AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();
                    if (activatedEventArgs.Kind == ExtendedActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch)
                    {
                        var commandLineArgs = activatedEventArgs.Data as CommandLineActivatedEventArgs;
                        if (commandLineArgs != null)
                        {
                            string arguments = commandLineArgs.Operation.Arguments;
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log or handle unexpected errors gracefully
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error during activation: {ex.Message}");
                }
            });

        });
    });

    return builder.Build();
}


<Extensions>
    <uap5:Extension
    Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
    Executable="MyAppHR.WinUI.exe"
    EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
        <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
            <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyAppHR.exe" />
        </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
    </uap5:Extension>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
        <uap:Protocol Name="myhr-kiosk">
            <uap:DisplayName>MyAppHRKiosk</uap:DisplayName>
        </uap:Protocol>
    </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>

--Edit--
Here I am using single app instance. So I kill the new app instance and pass arguments to the old one. Inside OnAppInstanceActivated, I can access the arguments. But I cannot pass them to the OnActivated.
 public App()
 {
     var singleInstance = AppInstance.FindOrRegisterForKey("SingleInstanceApp");
     if (!singleInstance.IsCurrent)
     {
         var currentInstance = AppInstance.GetCurrent();
         var args = currentInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();
         var commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
         var commandArgsString = string.Join(" ", commandLineArgs);
         singleInstance.RedirectActivationToAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
         return;
     }
     singleInstance.Activated += OnAppInstanceActivated;
     this.InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void OnAppInstanceActivated(object? sender, AppActivationArguments e)
 {
     var arguments = e.Data as ILaunchActivatedEventArgs;
     Services.GetRequiredService<ILifecycleEventService>().OnAppInstanceActivated(sender, e);
 }


delegate void OnAppInstanceActivated(object? sender, AppActivationArguments e);

static class WindowsLifecycleExtensions
{
    public static IWindowsLifecycleBuilder OnAppInstanceActivated(this IWindowsLifecycleBuilder builder, OnAppInstanceActivated handler)
    {
        builder.AddEvent(nameof(OnAppInstanceActivated), handler);
        return builder;
    }

    public static void OnAppInstanceActivated(this ILifecycleEventService lifecycle, object? sender, AppActivationArguments e)
    {
        lifecycle.InvokeEvents<OnAppInstanceActivated>(nameof(OnAppInstanceActivated), del => del(sender, e));
    }
}


Have you tried this solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73217714/9644964. You can also refer to Windows platform protocol activation #6493.
